# Webform: get field value from the Entity select option

Tags: 8, webforms

I have an entity select list based on **View** which collects a list of groups and their corresponding email address(may not be unique!). 
It seems that there is [bug](http://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2174633) in **entity_reference.module** so only titles of nodes are displayed.

I want to send emails based on the selected group. I have tried to set the **Custom To email address** using tokens but failed.

```
[webform_submission:values:groups:0:entity:field_email:*]
[webform_submission:values:groups:0:entity:field_email:value]
[webform_submission:values:groups:field_email:value]
```

Do I type the wrong tokens or is there any other alternative solution for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get all three of the below tokens to pull the single first email address for the group node's field_email.

[webform_submission:values:groups:entity:field_email]
[webform_submission:values:groups:0:entity:field_email]
[webform_submission:values:groups:0:entity:field_email:value]

Only [webform_submission:values:groups] returns 'Node Title (NID)'.